# SQL databases with names longer than 31 characters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql

My organization has an SQL Server with many databases with names longer than 31 characters. These are not recognized by ArcCatalog (or ArcMap). We can't change the names of these databases, because they're important for a wide variety of uses outside of ArcGIS. Is there a workaround for this problem? We're unable to use ArcGIS as a regular part of our workflow until this matter is resolved.

This limitation is described here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/enterprise-geodatabase-limits.htm

Comment: can you duplicate/clone the schema (with a rename)? goldengate can keep them in sync near real-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't do it because of large database names, I have in the past created a special database for ArcGIS to connect to.  Then within that database I create [synonyms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql) or [views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql) for the tables that ArcGIS requires access to.

So as a quick nasty example.

```
-- Create a mapping database
CREATE DATABASE ArcMapping;
GO

-- Optionally create a schema
USE ArcMapping
GO
CREATE SCHEMA db1;
GO

-- Create a synonym
CREATE SYNONYM db1.myTable FOR extremely_verbose_database_name_example.dbo.myTable;
GO

-- Or a view
CREATE VIEW db1.MyTable_vw AS
SELECT Something
FROM extremely_verbose_database_name_example.dbo.myTable;
```

Then connect to that database and map from the synonyms or views.

Comment: Thanks @MickyT , I had our database guy create me a view that only shows the fields I'm interested in since mine is a read-only user to that database.